# Wordpress nav_menu_css_class theme filter is not being called

Tags: theme-development, menus, filters

I'm having problems getting a filter to work. I'm trying to add a class to each `<li>` element of a menu. This is on my theme's `functions.php` file:

```
/**
 * Adds custom classes to the items in the nav menu
 *
 * @param array $classes Classes for the body element.
 * @return array
 */
function nav_menu_item_classes( $classes, $item, $args, $depth ) {

    // This is what I used to check that it's not working
    error_log("is nav_menu_item_classes working?");

    if ( 'menu-1' === $args->theme_location ) {
        // Add the Bootstrap nav-item class
        $classes[] = 'nav-item';
    }

  return $classes;

}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'nav_menu_item_classes', 10, 4 );
```

This is how I call the menu on my `header.php` file:

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
        'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
        'menu_class'     => 'navbar-nav',
    ) );
?>
```

Everything seems to match, yet the filter is not executed. What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure error logging is turned on? Does a `wp_die` also get called? `li` tags already get a `menu-item` CSS class, can you not use that instead?

Comment: Yes, error logging is on since I tried another functions to check whether they were working or not. `wp_die` doesn't get called when I add it to this filter's function. I could use the CSS class they have by default, `page_item`, but since I'm using Bootstrap it would be nice if I could use their code as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`nav_menu_css_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_css_class/) filter is located in the [`start_el`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/start_el/) function of WP's walker class. As you can see in the source, there is no conditional execution here, so once the walker is called, the filter must be applied.

This bring us to [`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/), which calls the walker (through some intermediate calls) on the line where it says: `$items .= walk_nav_menu_tree( $sorted_menu_items, $args->depth, $args );`. So, if anything prevents the filter to be called, it must happen before this line. Actually there are three possibilities:

1. First you see a filter called [`wp_nav_menu_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_args/). If this is used it could be adding a custom walker that does not call the filter.
2. Secondly there is the [`pre_wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_wp_nav_menu/) filter. If this is used, the rest of the function is short circuited and never reaches the walker.
3. Finally, if there are no items in your menu and no fallback is defined the walker will also be skipped. If there is a fallback (possibly added with `wp_nav_menu_args`) this will produce the output in stead of the walker.

Comment: Hm, I've been looking in my function files to check if I was using any of those filters (1 & 2) anywhere but no, I don't use them. I only use `register_nav_menus` on the theme setup function to register the menu. As for 3, the menu I'm trying to display has items.

Comment: It might be a plugin

Comment: I've now tried disabling all plugins, to no avail

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of options then.

Comment: I'm so sorry. Apparently you need to create a menu MANUALLY on the menu view. I created it (just clicking on the save button) and everything works now.