# nav_menu_css_class add_filter is never called

Tags: menus, filters

I try to use **nav_menu_css_class** filter with add_filter in worpress but it seems that it's not working ( i tried an echo or diein the function but never acces it). I just added a register_nav to add a menu. i read this article [Wordpress nav_menu_css_class theme filter is not being called](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309799/wordpress-nav-menu-css-class-theme-filter-is-not-being-called) but that does not solve my pb.
I used this code:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', function($classes){
   var_dump($classes);
   die();
})
```

here is my  wp_nav_menu

```
wp_nav_menu([
        'theme_location' => 'header',
        'container' => false,
        'menu_class' => 'nav__menu'
    ]);
```

i am tryng to use this filter to remove '**current_page_parent**' class in some cases
Any idea? thanks

Comment: where is the code located? Is it inside `functions.php` or a plugin? Is it in inside another function? Are you using a block based theme or are you calling `wp_nav_menu`? If so how is it being called? The question you linked to talks about custom nav walkers but if your themes custom nav walker does not call this filter then it will never be called

Comment: in the begining it was located in a plugin and it doenst worked. I took the code and put it in functions.php, same problem. I am using wp_nav_menu

Comment: can you edit your question to include the `wp_nav_menu` code? Why are you trying to filter the nav menu classes? Try to make sure your question inludes everything that anybody could possibly want to know about it to avoid back and forth

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.